# Most useful LaTex -macros? Help me to understand a statement with `\[p][s][frac|mat]`

Tags: macros, tex-core

I want to understand the below, source [here](http://poisson.phc.unipi.it/~maggiolo/index.php/2008/12/how-to-take-lecture-notes-with-latex/#more-356). I am studying material related to real-time-Texing like [here](http://stacky.net/wiki/index.php?title=Advice_on_real-time_TeXing).

> *As for fractions and matrices, I prefer using LaTeX macros instead of snippets. The most useful macros I use are the **\[p][s][frac|mat]**:
>   fraction or matrices, with parenthesis if there is the “p”, small if
>   there is the “s” (small means suitable for in-line math). Analysts may
>   want to have macros for (partial) derivatives; and remember that to
>   write differentials you have to write \mathrm{d} t, not simply d t!
>   The macros file I use is here (use it with usepackage{Commons}).*

Please, provide examples how to use the `"most useful macros"` there and do not hesitate to recite. I can understand `\frac 12` i.e. half i.e. 0.5 but what does this `\[p][s][frac|mat]` mean?

Comment: **Context:** *I am investigating this issue partly to my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/204393#204393) about note-taking -- trying to understand real-time TeXing. Some authors say that macros are not important (personally I use them very rarely, I try to keep base intact/minimalistic) but I still would like to understand this because I have never really understood the difference between LaTex and TeX, I have taken LaTex as face value.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author is referring to a series of commands he has defined and that are part od the file `Commons.sty` (the file can be found following a link in the site you linked to in your question); they basically are shortcuts allowing you to write fractions and matrices with or without delimiters; in the following document I've extracted the definitions from `Commons.sty` and provide an example of their use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\newcommand{\pa}[1]{\left(#1\right)} % encloses the argument using stretchable parentheses
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left[#1\right]} % encloses the argument using stretchable square brackets

% matrices for displayed expressions
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}} % no delimiters
\newcommand{\pmat}[1]{\pa{\mat{#1}}} % parentheses as delimiters
\newcommand{\bmat}[1]{\bra{\mat{#1}}} % square brackets as delimiters

% variations of \frac and \sfrac
\newcommand{\pfrac}[2]{\pa{\frac{#1}{#2}}} % enclosed in parentheses
\newcommand{\bfrac}[2]{\bra{\frac{#1}{#2}}} % enclosed in square brackets
\newcommand{\psfrac}[2]{\pa{\sfrac{#1}{#2}}} % sfrac enclosed in parentheses
\newcommand{\bsfrac}[2]{\bra{\sfrac{#1}{#2}}} % sfrac enclosed in square brackets

% for small matrices to be used in in-line expressions
\newcommand{\sm}[1]{\begin{smallmatrix}#1\end{smallmatrix}} % no delimiters 
\newcommand{\psm}[1]{\pa{\sm{#1}}} % parentheses as delimiters
\newcommand{\bsm}[1]{\bra{\sm{#1}}} % square brackets as delimiters


\begin{document}

\[
\pfrac{1}{2}\quad
\bfrac{1}{2}\quad
\psfrac{1}{2}\quad
\bsfrac{1}{2}\quad
\mat{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0}\quad
\pmat{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0}\quad
\bmat{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0}\quad
\]

$\sm{1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}\quad\psm{1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}\quad\bsm{1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if you save the file Commons.sty in a convenient place (your local tree, for example) where TeX can find it, you can load the package and directly use the commands, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Commons}

\begin{document}

\[
\pfrac{1}{2}\quad
\bfrac{1}{2}\quad
\psfrac{1}{2}\quad
\bsfrac{1}{2}\quad
\mat{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0}\quad
\pmat{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0}\quad
\bmat{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0}\quad
\]

$\sm{1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}\quad\psm{1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}\quad\bsm{1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}$

\end{document}
```

As a side note, I would have defined `\pmat` and `\bmat` using directly `bmatrix` and `pmatrix` as provided by `amsmath`.

Comment: @hhh he saves a few keystrokes; instead of, for example, `\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}`, he can write `\mat{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}`.

Comment: How to read this `"\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}`"? `"[1]"`? 3 blocks: \mat is the command, [1] is a divider and the last part is the new -command with place-holder?

Comment: @hhh maybe I don't understand you. Are you familiar with the use of `\newcommand` or is that precisely what you are asking?

Comment: Yes after thinking a bit, `[n]` is the amount of parameters where `n` is the amount. `\[p][s][frac|mat]`, is this some Regex? `|` is XOR? `[p]` means at least one p or no p? This is confusing notation, 3 blocks with no specifiers. `[...][...][...]`, what does this mean?

Comment: @hhh `\mat` is the command that will be defined; `[1]` declares that it has one argument (mandatory in this case); the next part: `{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}` is the definition of the command; it indicates that the argument will be typeset inside a matrix environment.

Comment: Updated, can you understand the Regex-looking -block `[...][...][...]`? I think `\` is just it but this bock makes no sense. Each part `[...]` must be satisfied but then empty set also possible? Then just `\`? I cannot understand, abuse of notation?

Comment: @hhh [here (LaTeX Wikibook)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX) you can find a description of `\newcommand`. Regarding your last question, do you mean this `\[p][s][frac|mat]`? If so, it's simply the concise way in which the author refers to the series of `\mat` and `\frac` commands he has defined. He tried to encompass in one simple expression of the possible variants he defined. Of course, his expression is merely notational.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6008/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-hhh)

Answer (score 1):

I don't want that Gonzalo Medina's words disappear so I attach them here from the chat. He clarifies the odd notation below. I bolded the clarifying point, thank you.

> The author chose [p][s][frac|mat] as a simplified (yet not entirely
>   correct) way to refer to a whole family of commands he defined (the
>   ones I explained in my answer). **With [p][s][frac|mat] he wants to
>    refer quicly to \frac, \pfrac, \psfrac, \mat, \pmat, and the \mat
>    version with an "s" which according to his notation should be \psmat,
>    but that he really named \psm.** Anyways, don't pay too much attention
>    to the [p][s][frac|mat] notation; it is not relevant to the commands
>    he defined; it was merely a "notational trickery" (that has nothing to
>   do with LaTeX) that he selected to quickly refer to the family of
>   commands that serve as shortcuts for matrices and fractions with or
>   without delimiters. What really matters are the commands themselves.
>   **He chose p as a mnemonic for "*p*arenthesized", so \pmat represents a
>    matrix using *p*arentheses as delimiters, \pfrac is a fraction
>    delimited by parentheses, etc. The "s" stands as a mnemonic for
>    "small", so \psm (which should have been \psmat, but he decided to use
>    only \psm as the intent is to save keystrokes) represents a
>    parenthesized small (for in-line use) matrix, etc.**